# How to handle globally parsing errors using GsonConverter

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, rx-java, custom-error-handling

I am using RxJava, retrofit, GsonConverter factory. I need to handle errors while parsing retrofit responses globally. I tried to write custom parser but i can't access to response url to pass it to my analytics service. Is there any posiible way to implement it correctly

```
class GsonResponseBodyConverter<T>(
        private val gson: Gson,
        private val adapter: TypeAdapter<T>,
        private val analytics: Analytics
) : Converter<ResponseBody, T> {

    private val errorResponseSubject = PublishSubject.create<Pair<Throwable, String>>()

    init {

        val errorResponseFlowable = errorResponseSubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)

        val disposable = Flowables.combineLatest(
                errorResponseFlowable,          
                Mapper::exceptionToEntity
        )
                .flatMap { analytics.saveError(it).andThen(Flowable.just(Unit)) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO)
                .subscribe({ /* no-op */
                    print(it)
                }, RxThrowable.printStackTrace(logger))

    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun convert(value: ResponseBody): T {
        val jsonReader = gson.newJsonReader(value.charStream())

        return value.use {
            runCatching {
                val result = adapter.read(jsonReader)
                if (jsonReader.peek() != JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    throw JsonIOException("JSON document was not fully consumed.")
                }
                result
            }.getOrElse { error ->
                errorResponseSubject.onNext(Pair(error, URL - I don't have access to url here!))
                throw error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `GsonResponseBodyConverter` class has already the `analytics` property; can't you access that in the `convert` function to obtain the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue using converter and call adapter hybrid thing) https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2267/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.